# Not able to render element using React.render - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am a starter in ReactJS, so may be its a very basic question.

Following is my code which is throwing error in the console - `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

I am following the tut from here - [Scotch Tut Link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/learning-react-getting-started-and-concepts) but unable to find out what I am doing wrong at the first step.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Example 1</title>
    <script src="lib/react-0.11.2/build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/react-0.11.2/build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="compOne"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        React.render(
            <p>This is a test !!!</p>, 
            document.getElementById('compOne')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

FYI - Path to library files are correct as I checked it in the page source.

Comment: Your code seems to work properly, as tried in this fiddle : 
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/14895/)

Try and replace your library files with a direct link to include react library and see if it works.

Comment: That post is super old! You shouldn't be using React this way! React has come a long way since then. I would suggest follow a more recent tutorial, say late 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `/** @jsx React.DOM */` in script text/jsx , find sample below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.2/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    React.renderComponent(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('container'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```